# AT-SPI for Google Chrome in Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, accessibility

I have been finding the way to get the urls of opened tabs of the browsers of Firefox and Chrome using Accessibiltiy.

I found that Firefox can get the urls using at-spi, but Chrome can get the url of focused tab a few months ago.

I have gotten a new result recently during the test. It is that I cannot access the child of Chrome using Accessibility, so I don't even know the url of focused tab.

"atspi_accessible_get_child_count" returns 0.

But as I said earlier, it worked on Chrome 31 version.

According to Assistive technology support, there are not tools to test accessibility in Linux.

Chrome does not support Accessibility anymore?

Answer (score 2):

You need to start Chrome like this:

`ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED=1 chrome --force-renderer-accessibility`

Both of these are necessary. For electron apps, `ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED=1` seems to be enough, at least that was the case with VSCodium and Signal Desktop.

On Windows, this is not necessary because a11y enables itself once a known screen reader is detected (afaik), but Orca under Linux is apparently not known.

Answer (score 0):

There is the answer in [Chrome Accessibility](http://www.chromium.org/developers/accessibility/linux-accessibility).

That says accessibility of Chromium on desktop Linux is not really supported currently.